# Is uninstalling via software center the equivalent of "apt-get purge"?

Tags: apt, software-center, purge

Is uninstalling via software center the equivalent of `apt-get purge`?

Or perhaps it is `apt-get remove`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is equivalent to `apt-get remove`. `purge` removes configuration files, etc., which the Software Centre does not.

Comment: Confirmed!  I installed `gtk-orphan` when I first installed Ubuntu as I didn't know about `apt-get` yet. (sou you can drop the "As far as I can tell" and change it to "Yes".  ;-)

Comment: Fabby, @Rinzwind is prescient. ;)

Comment: Oh and rationale: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2010-December/002711.html

Comment: @Rinzwind interesting. That idea looks to have died very quietly.

Comment: Yeah it did. It seems to be far too difficult to implement D:

Comment: @Rinzwind you gotta love the Way Back Machine: [Idea #24963: "Ubuntu Software Centre Removal of Configuration Files" - Ubuntu brainstorm](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918220452/http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24963/)

Comment: @blade19899 the last comment: "already implemented in Ubuntu Tweak" Do you know if that means Ubuntu Tweak has janitor-like abilities, or does it have a way to enable such an option in the Software Centre?

Comment: @muru at the top of my head, i think Ubuntu Tweak could purge the software, and not enable this as a feature in the Ubuntu Software Center. I might be mistaken. Not a Linux machine in sight to verify.

Comment: If I have already uninstalled via software center, can I run apt-get purge to remove the aforementioned config files?

Comment: @user3479458 yes.